# React Native Firebase. Platform specific installation. Where to get bundle ID?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am on the step of platform specific installation, iOS. 
It is said in instructions:

> A GoogleService-Info.plist file contains all of the information
>   required by the Firebase iOS SDK to connect to your Firebase project.
>   To automatically generate the plist file, follow the instructions on
>   the Firebase console to "Add Firebase to your app".

I enter the console and press "Add Firebase to my iOS app".
There I should enter some required iOS Bundle (packet) ID. It is said that I can see it in my xcode project. But I do not use xcode, I use react native. Where I can find this ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your project under 
          `projectroot/ios`

Click your project from the folder menu, select your target and go the 'General' Tab.
Under there you will find the 'Bundler Identifier'.

Comment: ProjectName/ios/ProjectName/ What next? There are 6 files there. Base.lproj, Images.xcassets, AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m, Info.plist, main.m What is 'General' tab?..

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out by myself what to do.
I've used `react-native init projectname` to create react native project.
In this case android project and ios project are created in root directory in android and ios folders respectively.
You need to open ios folder in Xcode and in General tab you can see the ID (as Brockify told; the only thing he didn't tell me - how to create ios project).